# How can I compute raster pixel width and height given raster bounds, row count, and column count?

Tags: raster, convert, resolution

Restated, how do I convert arc degrees to meters? For example, I have an elevation data raster that has the following metadata:

```
WEST LONGITUDE=64.97798789° E
NORTH LATITUDE=33.02003415° N
EAST LONGITUDE=66.03338707° E
SOUTH LATITUDE=31.98030163° N
PROJ_DESC=Geographic (Latitude/Longitude) / WGS84 / arc degrees
PROJ_DATUM=WGS84
PROJ_UNITS=arc degrees
EPSG_CODE=4326
NUM COLUMNS=9001
NUM ROWS=9001
PIXEL WIDTH=0.0001111 arc degrees
PIXEL HEIGHT=0.0001111 arc degrees
```

I can compute by hand the pixel width in arc degrees as follows:

```
(EAST LONGITUDE - WEST LONGITUDE) / NUM COLUMNS
```

Similarly, I can compute by hand the pixel height in arc degrees as follows:

```
(NORTH LATITUDE - SOUTH LATITUDE) / NUM ROWS
```

My question is how to compute the pixel width and height in meters.

Comment: Do you have access to GIS software? You could try and project it using meters as the unit of measurement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know how to use Global Mapper, which is where I obtained the sample data above. Through a sequence of steps I am able to use Global Mapper to see the pixel width and height as meters, but it's a hassle, and I want to be able to verify by hand what Global Mapper says.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware that the length of a degree of longitude varies with latitude (from infinitesimally small at the poles to roughly 111 km at the equator). I would have thought that to calculate cell dimensions in meters by hand would be more of a hassle than with e.g. Global Mapper.

Comment: That said, take a look at Wikipedia's Great-circle Distance page. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the quick-and-dirty (yet fairly accurate) conversion described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters/2964#2964).  As an example,

- **Pixel height** will be essentially constant (it is constant on a sphere and approximately so, to a fraction of a percent variation, on the WGS84 ellipsoid).  0.00011111 degrees = 1/9000 degrees = (approximately) 111111/9000 meters = **12.35** meters.
- **Pixel width** will be the cosine of the latitude times the height.  At the top of your grid, cos(33.02003415) = 0.8385, whence the width will be **10.35** meters.  At the bottom of your grid, cos(31.98030163) = 0.8482 for a width of **10.47** meters.  The variation is so small you can safely linearly interpolate between these to estimate widths at other locations in the grid.

Comment: Thanks! Quick and dirty is exactly what I was looking for...just something to get a figure of resolution in meters per pixel when Global Mapper reports it to me in arc degrees.