# Equations to convert from global cartesian coordinates to geographic coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, spherical-geometry, geography, xyz

First, I needed to convert geographic coordinates (like those received from GPS) to global cartesian coordinates. I found an earlier question ([How do I calculate a xyz-position of a gps-position relative to an other gps-position?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23793)) which worked perfectly. Now I need to go the other way around.

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates), there are equations to convert between those, but the equations from geographic to cartesian are different, and not indicating which is latitude and which is longitude. I know it's because it's not geographic per se, and I also know that those angles have different constraints than those of latitude/longitude. This makes me not trust the reverse equations there. I searched elsewhere but I couldn't find the answer.

Precision is not important. Consider a perfect sphere.

Comment: What software will you be using or are you trying to write the maths yourself? P.S. I haven't noticed any censoring on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I declared one point in each octant of the globe, transformed it to XYZ using the equations I had, and then tested martin f's answer. It didn't returned the same points. Then I delved deeper into Wikipedia's equations, and I finally understood how they worked. Then I adapted them.

```
latitude(r, x, y, z) = arcsin(z/r)(180/π)

longitude(r, x, y, z) = 
    if (x > 0) {
        arctan(y/x)(180/π)
    } else if (y > 0) {
        arctan(y/x)(180/π) + 180
    } else {
        arctan(y/x)(180/π) - 180
    }
```

(I wanted to write a piecewise function, but LaTeX isn't supported here) This is considering North and East as positive and right hand rule for XYZ, where Y is transverse to the plane that contains the Greenwhich meridian, positive to the East as well, and Z is aligned to North-South.

Thanks for helping me get there.

Edit: I just checked on Wikipedia, and it seems I learned the wrong right hand rule. Here, I mean X in the thumb, Y in the index finger and Z in the middle finger.

Answer (score 2):

The wiki reference you cite *is* based on a mathematical, not a geographic/cartographic, convention, as you say. It does however try to relate the geographic/cartographic equivalents. Here's my interpretation of the equivalencies:

```
Mathematics             Geography/Cartography
r, radial distance      R + h, radius + altitude
φ, polar angle          90 - φ, colatitude (latitude = 90 - colatitude)
θ, azimuthal angle      λ, longitude
radians                 degrees = radians * 360 / 2π
```

The conversion equations in the wiki article appear to be using the *physics* convention, not the mathematical one and confused me, too. (Maths and physics conventions have θ and φ swapped!) Another reference, [mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html), helps us out.

The equations you seek are

```
r = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)
h = r - R
λ = [arctan(y / x) * 360 / 2π]
  = [atan2(y, x) * 360 / 2π] ;; so as to account for quadrant or div-by-zero issues
φ = 90 - arccos(z / r) * 360 / 2π
  = arcsin(z / r) * 360 / 2π
```

Comment: I edited the answer - now correct, i hope ;-)