# Getting incorrect slope values from an ASTER DEM in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dem, slope, aster

I have a DEM layer from ASTER satellite and I want to get the slope information from it.

I use terrain analysis > slope, but the output is so wrong. Why is that?

Here is the DEM:

[image]

And here is the "Slope" that is totally wrong. It should stretch the values from 0 - 89.9097 but it does not.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aster DEMs are in EPSG 4326 (lat lon WGS84). According to the GDAL DEM documentation:

> For LatLong projections near the equator, where units of latitude and units of 
>     longitude are similar, elevation (z) units can be converted to be compatible
>     by using scale = 370400 (if elevation is in feet) or scale = 111120 (if 
>     elevation is in meters). For locations not near the equator, it would be best 
>     to reproject your grid using `gdalwarp` before using `gdaldem`.

In this answer for a problem with hillshading ([Scale and Z factor have no effect on hillshade analysis in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95337/scale-and-z-factor-have-no-effect-on-hillshade-analysis-in-qgis/95397#95397)) user @Luke provides a way to calculate the correct scale ("ratio of vertical to horizontal units") by multiplying the cosine of the latitude times 111320. The scale affects slope calculations.

In the image below I was able to produce slopes in **degrees** from a DEM in EPSG 4326 at latitudes ranging from 19°45N and 20°N. The scale (-s) was set to `104550.67`.

[image]

If you want to work with a DEM in a CRS that defines the measuring units of the coordinates and the elevations in meters you must reproject the DEM using raster/projections/warp (reproject). For example, reprojecting from EPSG 4326 (lat lon wgs84) to EPSG 32164 (UTM WGS84 14N). See below:

[image]

In this case, when calculating slope, the "ratio of vertical to horizontal units" (scale) would be set to 1.

Answer (score 5):

Probably because the projection was not in meters.

Slope with DEM projected in meters (UTM/31N: EPSG 25831):

[image]

Slope with the same DEM projected in degrees (WGS 84: EPSG 4326) and z = 1:

[image]

Slope with the same DEM projected in degrees (WGS 84: EPSG 4326) and z = 111320 (at the equator one horizontal unit, 1°, would correspond to about 111320 m):

[image]