# QGIS: smooth crs transformation

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have an elevation-raster in .hgt format with CRS EPSG:4326. My aim is to calculate aspect and slope which - as far as I understand - are difficult to obtain when using geographic CRS. Projected CRS are much better suited as map units are not degrees but meters (or the like).

So I tried and transformed the layer to EPSG:5677. However, the transformation produces very unpleasant artifacts (see pictures). The angles which were produced by the transformation have the potential to distort further analyses to a significant extent, I fear.

Can anyone suggest a procedure to minimise these unwished effects?

before transformation:

[image]

after transformation:

[image]

close before transformation:
 [image]

close after transformation:
[image]

Comment: Did you reproject your original raster? In this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143139/how-to-properly-get-the-slope-from-an-aster-dem-in-qgis/143235#143235 you can see how to reproject a raster properly

Comment: yes I did reproject it. I also tried using different resampling methods - near works worst, the others better but still far from satisfying, I think. I wonder whether there are other resampling methods not included in the standard tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no "perfect" transformation (which also is obvios). However, the warp function has different resampling methods to it. In this case, "cubic" seemed to work best. The result is not exact the same as the input layer, however, the undesired artifacts can be minimized and further analysis should only be affected to a minor extent.