# 'Scale' value in slope percent map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, scale, slope

What value should be used for scale while calculating slope percent in QGIS?

[image]

Some documents suggest is as 111120 and some as 365130.

I am using ESPG 4326 projection and do I need to convert this value to some other value using lat like given in this link:

[How to properly get the slope from an ASTER DEM in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143139/how-to-properly-get-the-slope-from-an-aster-dem-in-qgis/143235#143235)

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided says:

> scale=370400 (if elevation is in feet) or scale=111120 (if elevation is in meters)

So, what units are you using for elevation? Feet or meters?

And if you want to do this simpler, you could reproject to a CRS that uses the same units as your elevation measure.

Comment: how to know units used for elevation?

Comment: If you don't have metadata from the provider then check the height of some well known place.