# QGIS Slope Analysis produces strange values

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, slope

[image: Set up for slope analysis using a percentage]I am performing a slope analysis (Raster>Analysis>Slope) of a US Geological Survey DEM.

I am calculating the slope of a raster DEM saved as a TIF. I set up the slope analysis as per the picture below in EPSG 4326. I tick on calculate percentage and compute edges and leave all other variables as standard. When I calculate the slope in percentage I get really odd values being `e to the 6` as shown in the layer panels in the second item down, rather than between 0 and 90%. In the map the layer looks correct though and this is a hilly area. How do I make it so the values appear between 0 and 90?

Similarly when slope analysis is performed in degrees (not ticking the percentage option it returns nearly all cells as 90 degrees which isn't correct (layer 2 in layers panel).

How do I solve these problems?

[image: Map showing slope analysis output, 1st layers panel item is calculated using degrees and second is slope]

Comment: Please add more details on the exact settings you are using when conducting the slope analysis. Also please add single screenshots of all supposedly faulty layers.

Comment: Could it be that you are working in degree units CRS? See for example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143139/getting-incorrect-slope-values-from-an-aster-dem-in-qgis

Comment: Thanks that has worked, I multiplied by 111120 and I now have a sensible percentage. Thanks for your help

Comment: yes I think so. Just to check to calculate the slope as a % in m, I need to do the cos (lat)x 111320 for the hor to vertical factor, not just times by 111120