# Slope layer with false results in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dem, interpolation, slope

After the DEM creation, I wanted to create slope layer.

However, the result has not satisfied me. I don't think the slope map is correct. Have you ever encountered false calculated terrain map?

This is the DEM:

[image: DEM]

And this is the slope layer.

[image: SLOPE]

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in comments by [user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198166/false-calculated-slope#comment300477_198166) and [GerardoJimenez](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198166/false-calculated-slope#comment300478_198166) this is due to the horizontal coordinates `x` and `y` having a different unit of measurement from the elevation coordinate `z`.

For example, having latitude and longitude in degrees and elevation in meters.

So either:

- Reproject the CRS to a projected coordinate system (e.g. [Changing projection of geotiff file (raster data) in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222640/changing-projection-of-geotiff-file-raster-data-in-qgis/222675#222675)), or
- Scale the ratio between vertical and horizontal units (e.g. [Scale and Z factor have no effect on hillshade analysis in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95337/scale-and-z-factor-have-no-effect-on-hillshade-analysis-in-qgis/95397#95397)).