# Changing projection of geotiff file (raster data) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

After downloading an SRTM geotiff (DEM) from USGS's website, I would like to convert it from GCS to a projected coordinate system. After opening it in QGIS:

1. Is that enough if I simply just click on 'save as...' and set CRS from WGS84 to the preferred PCS?
2. Or should it be done like 'Raster > Projections > Warp'?

(I feel like it is not that easy and there is a trick somewhere...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Save As ...` only works for vector data.

`Raster > Projections > Warp` is dedicated for rasters. The reason behind are the many options you may need for reprojecting (and resampling) raster data.

In the background, GDAL ogr2ogr and gdalwarp are used respectively.