# Setting CRS automatically on Raster using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, land-classification

I'm currently working with the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin to help ID agricultural plots. However, when I attempt to set up the training I am given the error message.

> Error [61]: Projection error. Try to assign projection to raster
>   /Users/User/Documents/University/Thesis/Map
>   Layers/Rasters/orthophoto2015_1m.tif

The Raster is projected for EPSG 2039 ITM. Despite this, every time I load the Raster or save my work I am either asked to select a CRS, if one is not assigned as a default. I don't run into issues with training on rasters that have their own projection already.

In short, how do I set up a raster file so that it is automatically assigned a CRS without having to select one manually or have it set to that of the project?

Comment: The raster may be a tif, but not GeoTIFF, i.e. the projection information is not stored inside the file. Try to save to a new filename, or translate to format VRT, which wraps CRS information around the source file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export/save a layer composition to GeoTiff?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30498/how-to-export-save-a-layer-composition-to-geotiff). And related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222640/changing-projection-of-geotiff-file-raster-data-in-qgis/222675#222675.