# Scale factor for DEM Slope in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, scale, slope

My DEM raster coordinates are in WGS84: 45.4763884,-121.5736061 and vertical units are in feet I believe. I want to do a slope analysis. 
Do I need to add scale factor?

I have been seeing different answers all over and am confused.

Comment: Point some different answers you have seen.

Comment: on a different forum, one person said to use 111120 and then another person said not to because that is only valid a equator.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/95344/96925 This answer says to use 370400.

Comment: I also tried calculating my own using this answer's suggested formula for vertical units in "feet"     https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/95397/96925

Comment: Actually I just found out my DEM has vertical units in Meters.

Comment: I would rather re-project the whole DEM file to some projected, metric coordinate system that is reasonable for your area. UTM zone 10N might fit with your coordinates.

Comment: ok. Can you elaborate on your suggestion? For my own knowledge, I am very new to this game.