# DTED file project get squared by QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, srtm

I am quite new to the GIS world and I am trying to work with some DTED file from the SRTM project on QGIS. Unfortunately, when I add it as raster layer the program automatically shape it as a perfect 1:1 squared image. In order to be sure that the problem was not connected to the file used I checked it on MICRODEM where the resolution is showed correctly. This is quite a problem having to extract an actual 1:1 squared raster using specific coordinate but, due to this issue, the clipped raster has a wrong proportion.
[image: DTEM file on MICRODEM][image: DTEM file on QGIS]

I am not sure if there is an option to make QGIS shows the file with the original proportion or if it is maybe something else. If anyone has some suggestions or tool  I'd welcome it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DEM is in WGS84 (EPSG 4326), geographic coordinates in a decimal degree unit. You need to reproject your DEM with a projection that uses a meter unit, such as UTM with the proper zone that your DEM is located in.

For more details in how to project your raster data, check the following answer:
[Hillshade results look too grainy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/262820/63384)