# Creating slope map with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, slope

I created slope map with DEM model in ArcGIS Desktop. But it is only categorize in to two sections. I think it is problem with the horizontal and vertical scale. I used WGS84 coordinate system.

How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Supply a *z-factor* in your [slope tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/slope.htm) parameters to convert your elevation units (I assume meters) to the horizontal coordinate units of your DEM (degrees).

From the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/applying-a-z-factor.htm):

> The z-factor is a conversion factor that adjusts the units of measure
>   for the vertical (or elevation) units when they are different from the
>   horizontal coordinate (x,y) units of the input surface. It is the
>   number of ground x,y units in one surface z-unit. If the vertical
>   units are not corrected to the horizontal units, the results of
>   surface tools will not be correct.

Some roughly appropriate z-factors for particular latitudes are listed in the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/applying-a-z-factor.htm) (copied below) and for further info on calculating the z-factor yourself see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/95397/2856).

> ```
>     Latitude    Z-factor
>      0          0.00000898
>     10          0.00000912
>     20          0.00000956
>     30          0.00001036
>     40          0.00001171
>     50          0.00001395
>     60          0.00001792
>     70          0.00002619
>     80          0.00005156
> ```
>
> Note that as the range of latitude in your raster data increases, the more approximate the results will be.