# Hillshade not displaying correctly in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, resolution, hillshade

I have a large DEM of England that I have clipped to my study area and have been trying to generate a hillshade from. I tried a few variations with the parameters in altitude and azimuth (leaving z =1), but I continue to get this really grainy result using ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

The cell size is 0.00027777 decimal degrees. and I tried to re-sample to 1 but got an error that the size was too large. I tried running calculate statistics and building the pyramids on the original DEM but the result hasn't changed any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably generating your hillshade from a surface model that is referencing a geographic coordinate reference system like WGS84.  Re-project your data into a Cartesian coordinate reference system (like UTM) and then recreate your hillshade.

Answer (score 2):

You left z-factor = 1.

The [ArcGIS Pro Help for Hillshade](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/hillshade.htm) specifically states:

> If the input raster is in a spherical coordinate system, such as
>   decimal degrees, the resulting hillshade may look peculiar. This is
>   due to the difference in measure between the horizontal ground units
>   and the elevation z units. Since the length of a degree of longitude
>   changes with latitude, you will need to specify an appropriate
>   z-factor for that latitude. If your x,y units are decimal degrees and
>   your z units are meters, some appropriate z-factors for particular
>   latitudes are:
>
> ```
> Latitude     Z-factor
>  0           0.00000898
> 10           0.00000912
> 20           0.00000956
> 30           0.00001036
> 40           0.00001171
> 50           0.00001395
> 60           0.00001792
> 70           0.00002619
> 80           0.00005156
> ```

So pick or [calculate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/95397/2856) a z-factor close the central latitude. Or just reproject to a CRS that uses metres as the horizontal units.