# Decimal degree coordinates: how many decimal places to use for ...?

Tags: coordinates, ux, chart

When using coordinates in decimal degrees, how many decimal points actually make sense?

For example, say one is producing a table of locations of base camps in a report, there's no point in displaying a number like `62.946916, -135.018639` when `62.95, -135.02` is sufficient. On the other hand when giving someone a waypoint for GPS navigation `62.947, -135.019` is more warranted (manually keyed in, why type 6 digits when 3 will do?), while for locating a geocache 4 positions is desired, and 6+ for a survey stake.

In other words, what is the easiest way to determine for any given purpose how many decimal places should be displayed?

There are technical answers at [Algorithm for offsetting a latitude/longitude by some amount of meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters), but they're not readily adaptable to a quick reference handbook style of usage. I'm looking for a handy chart to refer to like *"the nth decimal place is X distance in ground units (at Y latitude)"*, or *"the nth decimal place is X distance in ground units (at ___ major city/landmark)"*.

Comment: The 111,111 number from the referenced doc will get you in the right neightborhood (though it's really 60 * 1852m = 111,120m per degree of subtended arc).  Using it, 6 places is ~10cm, 5 places is ~1m, and 4 places is ~10m (all at the equator)

Comment: ...not sure why I couldn't find [How to measure the accuracy of latitude and longitude?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude/8674#8674) when I posted this question...{shrug} It is very close to a duplicate, but not entirely because the answers there only deal with the equator. Ideally an answer would be added to the other Q to flesh out the latitudinal differences.

Comment: Good rule of thumb: five decimal places is one meter.  So you might want to specify the difference of adjacent tents to the nearest meter -- five decimal places.  If you are driving somewhere, knowing a business location to within 10m sounds pretty accurate, so four decimal places suits you.  If you are describing the location of a town -- well if it is 1km across or more, then two significant digits are plenty.