# Can you correct calculate the coordinates of a position given time and distance

Tags: coordinates

lets say i have a point on the map

```
New York, NY, USA
Latitude: 40.712784 | Longitude: -74.005941
```

If i move 10 metres north in 20 seconds ,can i use the coordinates i have to calculate the new coordinates?.

Comment: The answer to your basic question is yes, no problem.  Not sure if you were specifically looking for a technique to do this.  One thing is, to get distance calculations, you would have to convert lat/lon to a projected coordinate system and back again.

Comment: I need the technique. Basically this is my problem. I have the some coordinates. If i advance 10 metres north from my current point in 10 seconds,what will be my new latitude and longitude?. is there a technique i can use to calculate this?.

Comment: You can calculate position from great circle distance and bearing on a spheroid without an intermediate projection, but only by doing the requisite math.  The name of the problem is "geodetic forward"

Comment: Yeah, what Vince said.  Quick and dirty, not super accurate:  `estimate that 111,111 meters (111.111 km) in the y direction is 1 degree (of latitude) and 111,111 * cos(latitude) meters in the x direction is 1 degree (of longitude).`

Comment: Links to resources i can learn to do that is exactly what i would be interested in looking at. I do not have lots of gis background,i am just getting started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was a discussion on how to determine this using simple math, though you could do this more accurately if you used a GIS:

[Algorithm for offsetting a latitude/longitude by some amount of meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters)