# Setting cell size on "Polygon to Raster" tool, in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, polygon, units

How do I properly set the cell size that I want when converting polygons to raster files?

Also on the raster file **Layer Properties** what exactly does the **Cell Size** indicate, as it doesn't seem to correlate when I measure a cell?

Here is the background to my question.

I'm converting a shapefile that represents radio signal strength to a raster file.  The shapefile is made up of polygons that each represent average signal strength inside that polygon.  Each polygon is 3 x 3 arc-seconds with a single value to represent signal strength.  In my area 3 x 3 arc-seconds equates to about a 76.8 meter x 92.6 meter rectangle. 
When I convert to raster I would like to have similar resolution, so I was hoping that when I converted the shapefile each cell could be approximately the same size or smaller than the 76.8 meter x 92.6 meter rectangle polygons.

Using the "polygon to raster tool" **Figure 1**, it automatically sets the cell size to .0052.  What units is that in?

[image: Figure 1]

When I look at the new raster file, **Figure 2**, it clearly states that the cell size is .0052 x .0052 but I see nothing that specifies what units .0052 represents.

[image]

Measuring the individual cells however, I get measurements that don't seem to correspond to  .0052 of any units I've tried, **Figure 3**. Here using the pixel inspector I identified an individual cell and found it to be about 577.86 x 475.1 meter or 1,885.4 x 1,559.03 feet.

[image]

Just to be complete here are the Dataframe setting in **Figure 4** showing that the units are in Feet.

[image]

Comment: It's a long question.. I lost interest about halfway through. From what I did read you're confused about the cell size, you can specify an existing raster to match the cell size (don't forget environment SnapRaster as well) but if you use a numeric value it's always a **square cell**. If you want a 3x3 second cell project your input data into geographical (WGS84/Geographic should be good) then use a cell size of 0.000833333 (3 seconds as decimal degrees) *then* project the raster to your desired projected coordinate system (or not, it should still be mostly usable with project on the fly).

Comment: Yeah, maybe I added too much information.  But the main point is I'm trying to figure out how to specify cell size.  My conversion specifies cell size of .0052 but I have no idea what that means.  The cells it does render are  about 577.86 x 475.1 meters ( 1,885.4 x 1,559.03 feet).  So what does .0052 mean??

Comment: 0.0052 would be degrees (geographic units), perhaps your data or data frame is geographic and its using that as a measure, as for where ArcGIS gets the suggested default number 0.0052 from, it's a division of the extent of your dataset (wide or tall) by a constant number of pixels. Try changing 0.0052 to 0.000833333 to get cells approximately what you're after. What coordinate reference system is the derived raster in? I would hazard a guess and suggest that your output raster is in a geographic CRS which is why you're seeing rectangular cells.

Comment: Thanks!  That didn't solve all my problems, but at least now I know what I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the "polygon to raster tool" Figure 1, it automatically sets the cell size to .0052. What units is that in?

It is in **decimal degrees**. One degree of latitude is equivalent to approximately 111,111 m.
 <sub>(see for example, whuber's answer in [Algorithm for offsetting a latitude/longitude by some amount of meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters/2964#2964)).</sub>

The current pixel size of your raster in north-south direction is equivalent to:

```
0.0052 degrees x 111,111 meters/degree = 577.8 meters
```

So, if you want the pixel to be 92.6 meters in north-south direction, then set the resolution to:

```
92.6 meters / (111,111 meters/degree) = 0.0008334 degrees
```