# Offset Latitude and Longitude by some meters accurately - Reverse Haversine

Tags: python, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, haversine

I have a set of lat/long coordinates and need to offset the value to the "left" by < 10 meters. I calculate left by getting the direction my instrument is facing and use basic trigonometry to get the displacement in terms of lat/long. There is another similar answer on this forum but that does not talk about such small offsets. [Algorithm for offsetting a latitude/longitude by some amount of meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters)

```
d_lat = shift * math.cos(math.radians(90 - theta))
d_long = shift * math.sin(math.radians(90 - theta))
```

How do I accurately convert this small shift from meters to latitude and longitude values? Since my offset is by less than 10 meters I need it to be fairly accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Use [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/index.html):

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

geod = Geodesic.WGS84

lat1 = 0
lon1 = 0
theta = 0 #direction from North, clockwise 
azi1 = theta - 90 #(90 degrees to the left)
shift = 10 #meters

g = geod.Direct(lat1, lon1, azi1, shift)

lat2 = g['lat2']
lon2 = g['lon2']

print("lat2 = {:.8f}, lon2 = {:.8f}.".format(lat2, lon2))

# lat2 = 0.00000000, lon2 = -0.00008983.
```

Comment: this is lovely.